# Who is streetsmartaccord? Why do I have a folder /home/streetsmartaccord?

Tags: gnome

I have a file called /home/streetsmartaccord/.gvfs. (it is called a gvfs-fuse-daemon file).  My machine was brutally hacked and I'm wondering what this "streetsmartaccord" thing is--haven't been able to find a thing by googling.  Any insight would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a folder called `/home/streetsmartaccord/` then its likely that you have an user in this computer called `streetsmartaccord`. If you are the only administrator of this computer and you have not created this user, then it is likely someone else has gained control of your computer and is using it for nefarious purposes.

At the least disconnect the computer from the Internet. If it is connected by an Ethernet cable, unplug it. If it connected by WiFi, disable WiFi from the Network Connection icon on the top right corner of the desktop.

You should remove the user(s) you have not created. To do this for streetsmartaccord, open a terminal by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo deluser <username> <groupname>
```

In your case:

```
sudo deluser streetsmartaccord streetsmartaccord
```

Then delete the folder `/home/streetsmartaccord/`

This may not solve all the problems, but at least the user will not be able to login. You should look into how the intruder got access to your computer and close the security holes.

Best of Luck

Comment: You are welcome. If you think this answer is correct, you can put the green check mark next to it. This will help others.